# NavigationDrawer и Tabhost во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, fragmenttabhost

Добрый день, прошу помощи.

Суть проблеммы: табы которые я создаю внутри фрагмента, появляются при нажатии на элемент списка боковой панели и сразу же исчезают.

Приведу часть кода из MainActivity (не думаю что нужно приводить весь код):

**Вызываем мой фрагмент в котором нужно отобразить табы:**

```
@Override 
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) { 
        // update the main content by replacing fragments 
        Fragment fragment= new FragmentOrders(); 
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction() 
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment) 
                .commit(); 
      }
```

**А вот код моего фрагмента:**

```
public class FragmentOrders extends Fragment implements TabListener {

    @Override 
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override 
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false);

            ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar(); 
            actionBar.removeAllTabs();

            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); 
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab() 
                    .setText(getString(R.string.tab_orders1).toUpperCase()) 
                    .setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)) 
                    .setTabListener(this));

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab() 
                    .setText(getString(R.string.tab_orders2).toUpperCase()) 
                    .setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)) 
                    .setTabListener(this));

        return v; 
    }

    @Override 
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override 
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override 
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Буду признателен за помощь и объяснение причин такого поведения.

Comment: А вам что нужно сделать?